# Data table filter not working while searching for french characters

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm facing some issue in datatable searching with the French language when I'm searching for English it works but when I'm searching for French characters it is not working.

Please, any one can help me with this issue.

[Normal datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXbI6.png)

[Search English word in datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skloG.png)

[Search french word in datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B5W1.png)

Comment: You should post your Table structure and your Query to let someone help you

Comment: I have made a plugin for axactly this purpose -> https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/diacritics-neutralise